# How to "dismiss" a UIViewController that was set as rootViewController at MyScene (SpriteKit)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game using SpriteKit and I make a class for the pause

```
SettingsViewController *pause = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];

self.view.window.rootViewController = set;
```

Now I want to set

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = nil;
```

from pause and make the game go back from where it left.

Obs: I used

```
self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

to stop the SKScene.

Comment: Why don't you use segues for controlling the app flow?

Comment: This is dangerous. You cannot go about playing with the window's rootViewController. Please give us some more details regarding the flow that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show a custom view to hide it, when it comes back remove it. This allows you to show your game's splash screen when its in the background

```
public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
    {
        AddScreenCover ();
    }

public ScreenCoverView AddScreenCover(float alpha = 1f) {
        ScreenCoverView view = new ScreenCoverView (Window.Bounds);
        view.Alpha = alpha;
        Window.AddSubview (view);
        Window.BringSubviewToFront (view);

        return view;
    }

    public void RemoveScreenCover() {
        foreach (var view in Window.Subviews) {
            if (view.GetType () == typeof(ScreenCoverView)) {
                UIView.Animate (
                    .1,
                    0,
                    UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,
                    () => {
                        view.Alpha = 0f;
                    },
                    () => {
                        view.RemoveFromSuperview ();
                    }
                );


                break;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: That's in c#, but easily converted